# Underscore.js findLast() method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Does Underscore.js have a `findLast()` method or equivalent?

What is the best way to do [`.find()`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) but return the last item that matches in Collection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reverse the list and then use `find`:

```
_.find(list.slice().reverse(), iterator);
```

Read MDN for the documentation on [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

---

Unfortunately a collection in underscore may be either an array or an object. If your collection is an array then you're in luck. You can use `reverse`. However if it's an object then you'll need to do this instead:

```
_.find(Object.keys(list).reverse(), function (key) {
    return iterator(list[key], key, list);
});
```

You could write a `findLast` function for yourself:

```
_.mixin({
    findLast: function (list, iterator, context) {
        if (list instanceof Array)
            return _.find(list.slice().reverse(), iterator, context);
        else return _.find(Object.keys(list).reverse(), function (key) {
            return iterator.call(context, list[key], key, list);
        });
    }
});
```

Now you can use `findLast` like any other underscore method.

Comment: Thanks Aadit, for the detailed answer. :) Man I was hoping underscore.js had a version, seems like it fits with their already impressive collection... Edit: found this, https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/546 dang.

Comment: Using `Array.reverse` isn't ideal as it mutates the original list.

Comment: Also note that an object is essentially an unordered associative datastructure. Taking the keys of an object and then reversing their arbitrary order isn't a very meaningful operation. "Reverse" access is a concept that simply doesn't really extend beyond array-like collections.

Answer (score 4):

Underscore 1.8.0 introduced a method [findLastIndex](http://underscorejs.org/#findLastIndex) which can be used to accomplish this.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var index = _.findLastIndex(numbers, isOddNumber);
if (index > 0) { console.log(numbers[index]); }
// returns 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `reverse`, as suggested by @AaditMShah, is the easiest solution, but be aware that it manipulates the array [in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse). If you need to preserve the order of elements, you'd have to call `reverse` a second time, after you are done.

If you [don't want to use `reverse`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/869#issuecomment-10604111), you can

- use [Lodash](http://lodash.com/) instead, which provides `_.findLast`
- grab the relevant code from Lodash, spread out over [`findLast`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L3595) and [`forEachRight`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L3666) and make your own findLast.

This is what it looks like if you only deal with arrays and don't care about objects:

```
function findLast (array, callback, thisArg) {
    var index = array.length,
        last;

    callback = callback && typeof thisArg == 'undefined' ? callback : _.bind(callback, thisArg);

    while (index--) {
        if (callback(array[index], index, array) == true) {
            last = array[index];
            break;
        }
    }

    return last;
}
```

(It works, but I haven't tested it properly. So to anyone reading this, please run a few tests first and don't just copy the code.)